# Angular: Infinite scroll not working when using ngInclude in masonry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, masonry

I am using AngularJS with [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) and [angular-masonry](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry).

I currently have some parts of my frontend in PHP but I am trying to migrate everything to just HTML+JS.

This is currently working fine:

```
<div id="flagevent-container"
     infinite-scroll='getFlags()'
     infinite-scroll-disabled='loadingMore'
     infinite-scroll-distance='0'
     masonry="{'gutter': 10}" preserve-order load-images="false"
     item-selector=".flagevent">
  <div masonry-brick id="flagevent{{flagevent.id}}" class="flagevent"
       ng-repeat="flagevent in flagsInWall">
    <?php include "flagevent.inc.html"; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to move from PHP's `include` to Angular's `ng-include`. I will insert it at the `masonry-brick` level:

```
<div id="flagevent-container"
     infinite-scroll='getFlags()'
     infinite-scroll-disabled='loadingMore'
     infinite-scroll-distance='0'
     masonry="{'gutter': 10}" preserve-order load-images="false"
     item-selector=".flagevent">
  <div masonry-brick id="flagevent{{flagevent.id}}" class="flagevent"
       ng-repeat="flagevent in flagsInWall"
       ng-include="'flagevent.inc.html'">
  </div>
</div>
```

But then infinite scroll is not working; method `getFlags()` gets called repeatedly without scrolling, thus retrieving all items, and all elements get loaded at once.

What's happening?

Comment: could it be that since you are loading the content on the client side now ,instead of sending it from the server,the 1st time the page loads the infinite scroll content is empty thus immediately reaching the end and calling getFlags?

Comment: Hmmm sounds reasonable...

Comment: Still if all the getFlags function does is to add some values in the flagsInWall variable it should only be called once. :/

Comment: Each time it calls a service that returns a number of objects which get added to `flagsInWall`, but should only be triggered by approaching to the end of the scroll, rather than doing all the calls together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option was to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) `throttle` function and let `infinite-scroll` call a throttled version of the original function. Like that, some time is allowed for the contents to be generated and fulfill the scroll before `infinite-scroll` calls it again, as suggested by @toskv:

```
$scope.throttled = _.throttle($scope.getFlags, 500, {'leading': true, 'trailing': false});
```

Attributes `'leading'` and `'trailing'` mean 'listen only to the first call to `getFlags()` if the function is called before 500 ms, and do not call it one more time in the end'.

`infinite-scroll` should now use the throttled function:

```
<div id="flagevent-container"
     infinite-scroll='throttled()'
     infinite-scroll-disabled='loadingMore'
     infinite-scroll-distance='0'
     masonry="{'gutter': 10}" preserve-order load-images="false"
     item-selector=".flagevent">
  <div masonry-brick id="flagevent{{flagevent.id}}" class="flagevent"
       ng-repeat="flagevent in flagsInWall"
       ng-include="'flagevent.inc.html'">
  </div>
</div>
```

The next call after 500 ms will be executed, but by then, the content loaded by `ng-include` can already be generated. I guess this needs to be adjusted to each case.